# HTML equivalent of PHP include for JavaScript parts

Tags: javascript, php, html, include, doctype

I'm looking for a Javascript equivalent of a technique I've been using in PHP. That is, to place even the most basic page setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

...in a php file like 'doc_start.php' and then start every page in my site with...

```
<?php require_once('/path/to/doc_start.php); ?>
```

Now I need to begin a project that's strictly HTML and JS (no PHP) and want a similar way to avoid duplicating basic, common HTML elements. Obviously, I want to do more than this very basic stuff, like import JQuery in every page, link to a common stylesheet, etc. Again, all easy in PHP, but I'm still kind of a newbie in JS.

I've read about HTML5 includes, but can't seem to find anything that addresses what I want to do

Comment: I disagree with the notion that this is a duplicate question. OP does *not* want to know how to include one JS file into another but how to include one part of an HTML document into another -- comparable to what PHP's `include` does, or templating engines. Don't always be so quick to close stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to import other pages into your current document, you need to use a link tag.

For example....

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="/path/to/imports/stuff.html">
</head>
```

This will allow you to reference other html, css or javascript documents into your page without copying and pasting the same code within each page.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and PHP are different languages for **very** different purposes. But assuming you have some element you don't want to repeat some elements one solution is the following:

Save the HTML elements that you don't want to keep repeating as a string. Then use the `.innerHTML` property to add elements.

The `.innerHTML` property stores the mark up of an element as a string.

For example, if we have the following `<div>`:

```
<div class="example"> <br> Hello there this is a test! </div>
```

...and we use `.innerHTML`:

```
console.log(document.querySelector(".example").innerHTML);
```

It will output "`<br> Hello there this is a test!`".

We can add to the `.innerHTML` using the += operator. So if you want to add something inside the body it's as simple as:

```
var something = "some HTML";
document.body.innerHTML += something;
```

Hope this was what you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The fetch() method works very well for this:

```js
fetch('file.html')
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(data => {
     // Use the contents of the file here
     console.log(data);
   })
   .catch(error => {
     console.log('An error occurred:', error);
   });
```

or XMLHttpRequest:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'file.html', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
     // Use the contents of the file here
     console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }
};
xhr.send();
```

These two methods are equal.
I hope that answers your question !